# Proving something is a norm

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

Let $a<b$ be real numbers and $X=C[a,b]$ be the space of continuous functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$

Prove that $||f||_1 = \sup _{t \in [a,b]} |f(t)|$ indeed defines a norm on $X$.

The general definition is:

Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R$. A norm on $X$ is a map $||.||: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that@

($1$) $||x|| \geq 0$ for all $x \in X$ and $||x||=0 \iff x=0$

($2$) $||\alpha x ||= |\alpha| ||x||$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, $x \in X$

($3$) $||x+y|| \leq ||x||+||y||$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$

I cant even do the first condition because i dont know how it works with the "$x$" being inside the norm symbol. I feel that if i see how the first condition checks, i would be able to do the rest. Please help.

Comment: Fix $[a, b] = [0, 1]$ and consider the function $f(x) = x$. Can you see what $\|f\|_1$ is?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese would it be 1? we dont have what $f(x)$ is in ours so i still dont know how it works...

Comment: In your conditions, $x$ refers to a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Could you prove that $||x||_1 = \sup _{t \in [a,b]} |x(t)|$ is $\ge0$? Also, are you sure it's not $||x||_{\infty}$?

Comment: The "$x$" in your case will be an element of your space. Since you consider the particular space $C[a,b]$, then it will be a continuous function. Perhaps Michael's comment is a tad misleading as he uses $x$ as argument for his function...

Comment: Would also note that in (2) it should be $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}, x\in X$, and in (3), it should be $x,y \in X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition says $||x||\geq0$ for all $x\in X$. In your case $X=C[a,b]$, such that elements of $X$ are continuous functions $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$.

In other words, you have to prove $||f||\geq0$ for all $f\in X$.

Since $|f(t)|\geq0$ for any $t\in[a,b]$, you have $\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|\geq0$, proving $||f||\geq0$.

I think you'll be able to prove the second statement of the first condition, as well as the other two conditions. Good luck!

Comment: second part of first condition: suppose $||f||_1=0, then \sup |f(t)|=0$ which forces $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ so $f=0$. Then the reverse is suppose $f=0$ then $f(t)=0$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ so $\sup |0|=0=||f||_1$. is this OK? pretty unsure on the "forces" part, seems obvious though...

Comment: Yes, it's correct :) Whether you have to prove the "forces" part depends on what context you're working in. I'd say it is pretty obvious indeed. (btw, you can prove it by using that $|\cdot|$ itself is also a norm).

Comment: If you want the full proof, let me know and I'll add it to my answer... But maybe you want to try it yourself first. :)

Comment: Other remark: maybe in your case it'll be less confusing if you rewrite the conditions you need to check to contain $f$ as elements instead of $x$: (1) $||f||\geq0$ for all $f\in X$ and $||f||=0\iff f=0$. (2) $||\alpha f||=|\alpha|||f||$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in X$. (3) $||f+g||\leq||f||+||g||$ for all $f,g\in X$.

Comment: thanks, especially for the remark because it is VERY confusing otherwise. Ill have a go at the rest now

Comment: on (2), need to prove $||af||_1=|a|||f||_1$ so $||af||_1=\sup|af(t)|=\sup(|a||f(t)|)$ but then i dont know what to do...

Comment: $\sup(|\alpha||f(t)|)=|\alpha|\sup|f(t)|$, as $|\alpha|$ does not depend on $t$.

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ is an element that you can take norm of, and $0$ is an neutral element under addition (ie such that $0+f = f$). In your example it would translate to:

- $||f||_1\ge 0$
- $||f||_1 = 0$ iff $f(t)=0$ for all $t\in[a,b]$
- $||\alpha f||_1 = |\alpha|\cdot||f||_1$
- $||f + g||_1 \le ||f||_1+||g||_1$

So for example for the first we note that since $|f(t)|\ge0$ we would have that $||f||_1=\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|f(t)|\ge 0$.

I think you can do the rest now. The first three should be quite straight forward, but the last requires a little bit more work (but should hopefully be not to hard).